# How to debug nginx and php-fpm besides nginx -t, access log, error log and php*-fpm status?

Tags: nginx, php-fpm

Nearly two weeks I'm stuck with [this LEMP problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1024606/failed-to-implement-nginx-caching-connection-refused) in which I get only one error anywhere and I don't feel this error helps me to solve my problem:

```
*1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream,
client: MY_IP_ADDRESS, server: example.com, request: "GET /
HTTP/2.0", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000".
```

`nginx -t`, `access.log`, and `/etc/init.d/php*-fpm status`
 returns no additional errors.

It's not the first time I get a "vague" `connection refused` error from Nginx while no other error log indicates what might be the source of the problem:

How to further debug Nginx in such circumstances?

<sub>BTW, I tried to contact the Nginx developers on this but they have shutted down any reasonable option to contact them (for example, they don't get emails from Gmail senders or GitHub issues).</sub>

Comment: You got what looks like a reasonable answer on that question 6 hours ago. Have you tried that suggestion? If you want help on Server Fault we ask that you include relevant configurations here, rather than links to other sites.

Answer (score 3):

Your `nginx` config specifies that it is supposed to connect to `PHP-FPM` using TCP to `127.0.0.1:9000` but your `PHP-FPM` config specifies that it doesn't listen on TCP port 9000 but instead uses unix socket `/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock` so you get `connection refused`.